# Reading in a .csv file of p-values, how can I ignore/convert certain inputs?

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to read in a .csv file containing node data (p-values mostly) into my progam, but in doing so I have to convert them from strings into doubles. Here's the method for it:

```
public ArrayList<Node> getCSVFile(String file){


        String csvFile = file;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        ArrayList<Node> nL = new ArrayList<Node>();
        int count = 0;

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                String[] node = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


                double pVal = Double.parseDouble(node[4]);
                nL.add(new Node(count, node[0], pVal));

                count++;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    return nL;
}
```

The object Node is parameterized as Node(int, String, double), but the first line of the file I'm trying to convert is a column name, and I'm not entirely sure of the nature of the entries after that. Here's a look at the start of the file:

> GENE,COMMON,gal1RGexp,gal4RGexp,gal80Rexp,gal1RGsig,gal4RGsig,gal80Rsig
>   YHR051W,COX6,-0.034,0.111,-0.304,3.75720e-01,1.56240e-02,7.91340e-06
>   YHR124W,NDT80,-0.090,0.007,-0.348,2.71460e-01,9.64330e-01,3.44760e-01
>   YKL181W,PRS1,-0.167,-0.233,0.112,6.27120e-03,7.89400e-04,1.44060e-01
>   YGR072W,UPF3,0.245,-0.471,0.787,4.10450e-04,7.51780e-04,1.37130e-05
>   YHL020C,OPI1,0.174,-0.015,0.151,1.40160e-04,7.19120e-01,1.53950e-02
>   YGR145W,YGR145W,0.387,-0.577,-0.088,5.37920e-03,8.27330e-03,7.64180e-01
>   YGL041C,YGL041C,0.285,-0.086,0.103,4.46050e-04,4.50790e-01,7.03040e-01
>   YGR218W,CRM1,-0.018,-0.001,-0.018,6.13810e-01,9.79400e-01,8.09690e-01
>   YOR202W,HIS3,-0.432,-0.710,0.239,1.09790e-02,1.79790e-04,5.48950e-03
>   YCR005C,CIT2,0.085,0.392,0.464,4.18980e-02,1.53050e-06,2.74360e-06
>   YER187W,KHS1,0.159,0.139,-0.045,8.51260e-04,4.17830e-03,6.18020e-01
>   YBR026C,YBR026C,0.276,0.189,0.291,3.63320e-05,6.15230e-04,1.24430e-03
>   YMR244W,YMR244W,0.078,-0.239,-0.072,5.76050e-01,3.55240e-01,8.85690e-01
>   Etc etc..

So the code creates nodes for each line based on the first and fifth columns, as well as a unique counter. However how can I skip the first line that just has the column names? I'm a little hesitant to simply have something skipping all first lines in all files, as not all files read may have a string as a first line. Even then, are the following lines suitable for being converted to doubles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about skipping lines when parsing the double is not possible?
Like this:

```
public ArrayList<Node> getCSVFile(String file){
    String csvFile = file;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    ArrayList<Node> nL = new ArrayList<Node>();
    int count = 0;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] node = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            double pVal;

            try {
                pVal = Double.parseDouble(node[4]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                continue;   // Skip this line if this isn't a double
            }

            nL.add(new Node(count, node[0], pVal));

            count++;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return nL;
}
```

Comment: The one caveat with this is that you lose the ability to deal with 'actual' unexpected values. Once you're passed the first line, any bad data should (probably) result in an actual error - otherwise you could successfully read in half a file without realising that the other half was skipped because of bad characters. That said I think this answer achieves with OP was asking for.

Comment: Deyur is right in that this may just pass by half the file, but the try/catch solution is pretty much in line with what I was hoping for (file errors aren't really a major problem for what I want to do with it). Thanks! :D

Comment: Good point @deyur. Talex may want to replace the use of `continue;` by something else if any behavior other than skipping non regular data lines (like the header) is desired.

Comment: Gotcha. I might do it in future versions, but this is more than sufficient for now :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your existing method to:

```
public ArrayList<Node> getCSVFile(String file, int startAt){
```

and use `startAt` inside of your read loop to control how many lines are skipped. I'd recommend creating a default method that returns all lines:

```
public ArrayList<Node> getCSVFile(String file){
    return getCSVFile(file, 0);
}
```

Alternatively this could be a boolean if you know that you'll either want to skip the first line or none at all.

As for the second part of your question, many of those strings will not be parseable. You may want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)). But I'm not sure how you expect to parse or use a value like 'YHR051W' (since you said you wanted the first column).

Comment: Cheers, I've implemented something similar already, but is it possible to write something that automatically includes the first line if it can be converted, and excludes it if it can't?

Comment: In that case the solution provided by ulix is probably the way to go.